# SQL Server Reporting Services: how to insert calculated "intermediate" row

Tags: reporting-services

suppose i have the following Report:

```
Code, Year, Jan, Febr, March.... December, Total
 ABC  2011  13  883   2828      ....       3000
 ABC  2012  20  888   ....

 XYZ  2011 ....
 XYZ  2012 ....
```

I need to insert a "delta row" each 2 row (2 year) per code to have my report

```
 Code, Year, Jan, Febr, March.... December, Total
 ABC  2011  13  883   2828      ....       3000
 ABC  2012  20  888   ....
 Delta      +7  +5  .... 

 XYZ  2011 ....
 XYZ  2012 ....
 Delta ....
```

How to do this with Sql Server Reporting Services ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method to get this is:

1. Insert a second row in your innermost row group, possibly the details group.
2. Set the visibility of this row to be hidden `=IIF(Previous(Fields!Code.Value,"RowGroupNameGoesHere") = Fields!Code.Value , false, true )`
   [I know, redundant to have IIF to return true or false, but it makes troubleshooting easier and more flexible.]
3. Use the previous function in the cells of this row to get the difference between this and the previous item, something like `=SUM(Fields.QuantitySold.Value) - Previous(Sum(Fields!QuantitySold.Value),"RowGroupNameGoesHere")`

[I'm assuming you are pivoting with a tablix, and that your dataset doesn't have a different column for each month. If it does, then the same approach will work, but uses the appropriate field names, without SUM, in the formula in step 3.

This will generate a difference row for every row in the report, but then hide the ones that are between matching elements.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but i've another problem: how if i not have every time 2 years row (per group) ? If i use Previous i got a wrong data...

Comment: Adjust your visibility formula to hid those rows or change your math to handle those differently COUNT(Fields!Code.Value,"RowGroupNameGoesHere") = 2 should give you a start.